# Google Chrome GWT Dev Plugin doesn't work - help

Tags: java, gwt, plugins, google-chrome, uninstallation

I have just downloaded the Newest Google Chrome to test my gwt app... And, of course, in first gwt app running chrome demanded GWT plugin to be installed. So I did... All great but when gwt test app starts it doesn't work as in eclipse Design - Preview or IE8 etc. Instead of panels activation chrome shows me just a blank right frame :( Moreover, since then my FF 5.0 GWT dev plugin started do the same (blank) tricks as if it was replaced with the chrome one :( I think chrome caused all these things... I have already uninstalled chrome but my FF still tricks me with (blank) things...  So my question is...

How to uninstall the Chrome GWT plugin totally to be able reinstall all from up to down and not to have GWT dev plugins conflict or something which maybe causes the headache?

- My GWT version is 2.3
- OS: Windows XP Pro SP3
- IE8, FF 5.0.1 (Currently installed Internet Browsers)

All useful comments are appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite strange but I have found that the Chrome GWT Dev plugin doesn't support two included SplitLayoutPanels :(

I mean the bound like a...

> - SplitLayoutPanel A which contains SplitLayoutPanel B

IE 7 supports this kind of code but Chrome and even FF don't :(

That caused the development problem. So I replaced the second SplitLayoutPanel B to HorizontalSplitPanel and finally that solved the problem :)

I hope that can save one's day :)

Answer (score 0):

Might be far fetched, but have you checked that you're compiling against the correct user-agents in the module definition?

EDIT:
The module is the file ending with .gwt.xml and in that file you can specify which user agents to compile javascript for. In my module i'm having this line:

<set-property name="user.agent" value="ie6,ie8,gecko1_8,safari" />

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't have any compilation error but the thing is app runs fine in IE7 but doesn't run in FF 4.0/5.0/5.0.1 and google chrome as well :( Can it be a plugins conflict or something? How to know was the previously installed plugin uninstalled totally?

Comment: Maybe I need to clean something in my regedit manually and only then install new FF and its new GWT dev plugin?

Comment: But I don't know where to look at?

Comment: The module definition (as i call it) is the *.gwt.xml file. There should be a line that looks something like this: '<set-property name="user.agent" value="ie6,ie8,gecko1_8,safari" />' - I'll edit my answer instead :)